# Why can constructor syntax not be used with the "unsigned int" type?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer

Why is the following illegal in C++?

```
auto x = unsigned int(0);
```

Whereas the following are all OK:

```
auto y = int(0);
auto z = unsigned(0);
auto w = float(0);
```

or in general:

```
auto t = Type(... c-tor-args ...);
```

(with the exception of `Type` being `unsigned int`).

Comment: Of course you could just say 'auto a = 10u' but you probably knew that. The syntax you're using has nothing to do with construction, even if it superficially resembles it. Use literals of the correct type and that's that.

Comment: As a workaround, `template <typename T> using id = T;` so you can `auto x = id<unsigned int>(0);` or `auto p = id<int*>(nullptr);`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The syntax is [Explicit type conversion (functional notation)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast#Explanation) here. According to the grammatical rule, it only works with simple type specifier or typedef specifier (i.e. a single-word type name).

(emphasis mine)

> 2) The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (**in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid**), followed by a single expression in parentheses. This cast expression is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression.

You can change it to c-style cast expression or `static_cast`, or use it with typedef specifier as @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggested.

```
auto x1 = (unsigned int)(0);
auto x2 = static_cast<unsigned int>(0);
```

Quotes from the standard, [$5.2.3/1 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#1)

> A simple-type-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]) or typename-specifier ([temp.res]) followed by a parenthesized optional expression-list or by a braced-init-list (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer.

And [$7.1.7.2/1 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#1)

> The simple type specifiers are
>
> ```
> simple-type-specifier:
>     nested-name-specifieropt type-name
>     nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id
>     nested-name-specifieropt template-name
>     char
>     char16_t
>     char32_t
>     wchar_t
>     bool
>     short
>     int
>     long
>     signed
>     unsigned
>     float
>     double
>     void
>     auto
>     decltype-specifier
> type-name:
>     class-name
>     enum-name
>     typedef-name
>     simple-template-id
> decltype-specifier:
>   decltype ( expression )
>   decltype ( auto )
> ```

Comment: @Asu Yes, because it's a simple type specifier.

Comment: Could you be specific about where that quote is from? Thanks :)

Comment: The quote and the answer are saying different things; note the colon `:` in the quote. The quote says that the specifier must be a **single-word type name**, but the answer says that `single-word type specifier is not valid`.

Answer (score 21):

Because of parsing priority. The compiler is lost because `int(0)` is matched before `unsigned int`.

You have to enclose your type in parentheses:

```
auto x = (unsigned int)(0);
```

or use a typedef:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
auto x = uint(0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure "operator precedence" is the right term here.

Comment: I'm not sure either. What would you suggest? parsing priority ? I'm editing that way.

Comment: Parsing priority is probably sufficiently clear, but this is really just rules of the language's grammar. Function-style casts must be a single identifier.